# Spark Streaming to Kafka slow performance

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm writing a spark streaming job that reads data from Kafka, makes some changes to the records and sends the results to another Kafka cluster.

The performance of the job seems very slow, the processing rate is about 70,000 records per second. The sampling shows that 30% of the time is spent on reading data and processing it and the remaining 70% spent on sending data to the Kafka.

I've tried to tweak the Kafka configurations, add memory, change batch intervals, but the only change that works is to add more cores.

**profiler:**
[image: profiler snapshot]

**Spark job details:**

```
max.cores 30
driver memory 6G
executor memory 16G
batch.interval 3 minutes
ingres rate 180,000 messages per second
```

**Producer Properties** (I've tried different varations)

```
def buildProducerKafkaProperties: Properties = {
  val producerConfig = new Properties
  producerConfig.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, destKafkaBrokers)
  producerConfig.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all")
  producerConfig.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, "200000")
  producerConfig.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, "2000")
  producerConfig.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, "gzip")
  producerConfig.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, "0")
  producerConfig.put(ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, "13421728")
  producerConfig.put(ProducerConfig.SEND_BUFFER_CONFIG, "13421728")
  producerConfig
}
```

**Sending code**

```
 stream
    .foreachRDD(rdd => {    
        val offsetRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges

        rdd
          .map(consumerRecord => doSomething(consumerRecord))
          .foreachPartition(partitionIter => {
            val producer = kafkaSinkBroadcast.value    
            partitionIter.foreach(row => {
              producer.send(kafkaTopic, row)
              producedRecordsAcc.add(1)
            })

        stream.asInstanceOf[CanCommitOffsets].commitAsync(offsetRanges)
      })
```

**Versions**

```
Spark Standalone cluster 2.3.1
Destination Kafka cluster 1.1.1
Kafka topic has 120 partitions
```

Can anyone suggest how to increase sending throughput?

---

**Update Jul 2019**

**size**: 150k messages per second, each message has about 100 columns.

**main settings**:

```
spark.cores.max = 30 # the cores balanced between all the workers.
spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled = true
ob.ingest.batch.duration= 3 minutes
```

I've tried to use rdd.repartition(30), but it made the execution slower by ~10%

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use repartition as below -

val numPartitons = ( Number of executors * Number of executor cores )

```
stream
    .repartition(numPartitons)
    .foreachRDD(rdd => {    
        val offsetRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges

        rdd
          .map(consumerRecord => doSomething(consumerRecord))
          .foreachPartition(partitionIter => {
            val producer = kafkaSinkBroadcast.value    
            partitionIter.foreach(row => {
              producer.send(kafkaTopic, row)
              producedRecordsAcc.add(1)
            })

        stream.asInstanceOf[CanCommitOffsets].commitAsync(offsetRanges)
      })
```

This will give you optimum performance.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I've tried it and the performance decreased by 10%, the dag shows an extra step, I had to do the repartition on the RDD, because if you'll do it on stream it will change the class of RDD and you can't commit offsets

Comment: Can you please share the data size you are trying to process in each batch. Also what values you have set for Number of executors and Number of executor cores. As per my understanding one fixed configuration can't be optimum for all scenarios, based on data size and computations, Number of executor and Number of executors cores need to be changed.